# Object wont iterate

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4

Quick question:

```
if($subCategories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($_category->getId());){
```

Returns true, but then:

```
foreach($subCategories as $_subCategory):
```

Doesn't iterate. Can anyone explain to me why?

How can I test if a magento object will iterate?

Magento 1.9.x btw.

Comment: To debug I would start by checking what `$subCategories` exactly is in this case. What class it's an instance off, if a collection what the `->count()` is etc

Comment: @SanderMangel `->count()` was exactly what I was looking for! Many thanks (I was using `count()`). Add this as an answer and I will mark you as correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories()` returns a collection class on which you can use the `count` method

`$subCategories->count()`